# onSnapshot returns empty document change data when change.type is added

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm listening to a collection in Firestore using `onSnapshot`. Every time I add some data from my Python backend, it's reflected in Firebase console but not in my UI.

I properly checked that I'm listening to the right collection and my callbacks are proper, below is my code. When I remove `change.type`, `querySnapshot` first gives me empty change data then the data which I added from my backend.

```
from google.cloud import firestore

db = firestore.Client.from_service_account_json(CREDENTIALS_FILE)

collection_name = 'mycollection'
collection_ref = db.collection(collection_name)

message = {
 'data': 'testing'
}

collection_ref.add(message)
```

```
function subscribe_to_notifs(collection_name) {
 var firestore_db = firebase.firestore();
 var collection_ref = firestore_db.collection(collection_name);

 const handleActivitySubscriptionWithInvocation = countFunctionInvocation(handleActivitySubscription, 1);
 collection_ref.onSnapshot(handleActivitySubscriptionWithInvocation);
}

function handleActivitySubscription(querySnapshot) {
 querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
   console.log(change.doc.data()); // Here I get the data

   if(change.type === 'added') {
    console.log(change.doc.data()); // Here I get an empty response i.e {}
   }
 });
}

/* 
Firestore onSnapshot() sends initial payload which I don't want.
I only need to listen for updates in a collection
This function will make sure that the `subscription_function` is called 2nd time,
so that we get only the updates from a collection. 
*/
function countFunctionInvocation(subscription_function, invoke_before_execution) {
    var count = 0;
    return function (args) {
        count++;
        if (count <= invoke_before_execution) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return subscription_function(args, count);
        }
    };
}
```

I expect some data in `change.doc.data()`. What can be the  reason for this?

Note: Initially I've no documents in my collection, when I get some data I put it in to Firestore using Python Admin SDK.

Comment: Without seeing all your moving parts, it's really difficult to imagine what might be going on. Could you edit the question to give us assurance that all the other parts that you say are correct are actually correct?  You might still be doing something wrong.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated the code.

Comment: What is collection_name? What is the code that writes to collection_name? Please include enough code such that anyone can reproduce the issue exactly as you're seeing it.

Comment: @DougStevenson I figured out why I was getting empty data for `change.type === 'added'`, on using `add()` from Python SDK `onSnapshot()` method in client side receives `change.type === 'added'` with empty data first and then `change.type === 'modified'` with the data which was inserted into the collection. On using `set()` from Python SDK `onSnapshot()` receives `change.type === 'added'` with data which was inserted into the collection.